# How to get logged in user details from javascript - Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a custom share page with authentication as user. Now i want to enable few buttons in the page if the logged in user is a Manager. But i don't know how to find out the logged in user is a manager or Collaborator. Can someone please help me?

Comment: A bit more information would be useful here... what version of Alfresco are you using? Is it Community or Enterprise? How are you building the page - e.g. are you using standard Surf / YUI2 or are you building an Aikau page? All of this information will help your question be answered more effectively

Comment: HI Dave, I am using Alfresco v4.0.2 Enterprise edition and standard Surf / YUI2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all WebScript JavaScript controllers running on the Share tier you can access `user.isAdmin`. This will be a boolean value indicating whether or not the current user has Administrator privileges.

However, I'm not sure if this is what you mean because you have said "Manager" - if you mean that you want to know whether or not the current user is a Manager of the current site then it will be necessary to make a request back to the Repository using the site id from the page context, there are lots of examples of this in the Alfresco codebase - essentially it should look something like this:

```
var userIsSiteManager = false;
var json = remote.call("/api/sites/" + page.url.templateArgs.site + "/memberships/" + encodeURIComponent(user.name));
if (json.status == 200)
{
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
}
if (obj)
{
   userIsSiteManager = (obj.role == "SiteManager");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was also looking for the same. I tried the code, but i got an error :"Uncaught ReferenceError: remote is not defined ". After searching i came to know that remote.call method is not available in browser client side javascript. So is it proper to create a webscript for the same and invoke it using ajax call? Or is there any other better way? can you please suggest?

Comment: That code would be used in a WebScript JavaScript controller... you can call the same API from the client though. The site shortName would be available in the client on the `Alfresco.constants.SITE` constant. The API you would need to call would be /share/proxy/alfresco/api/sites/<site short name>/memberships"

Answer (score 0):

In browser javaScript you should use ajax request

```
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonPost({

  url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + webScriptUrl,
  dataObj: data,

  successCallback: {
    fn: succesCallback,
    scope: this
  },

  failureCallback: {
    fn: faliureCallback,
    scope: this
  }

});
```

pass your request params in dataObj javaScript object.

In repository webScript use `json.get("paramName")`

Then use

```
var site = siteService.getSite(siteId);

//person - current logged in user

site.getMembersRole(person.properties.userName)
```